# How to use binary classification for anomally detection in Keras for images?

Tags: python, keras, classification

I am new to ML and managed to get multi class classification running with nice accuracy. Now I am trying to do a classification of images but either match and not-match to my training images. I am using Resnet50 and InceptionV3 models in project. Now, I do have one set of images (matching) and I need to test my testing image is matched to it or not. This is also sometimes known as anomaly detection. I used Keras  classification method but using binary cross entropy before with two classes (good and bad - 1 dense layer) with using sigmoid for binary output. It worked fine but in new process, I don't have second class (no bad images) and I only have good. (Still 1 dense layer)
I have three training, validation and testing folders. Each folder has a single folder with images (one class).

This is how I did.
1. I set last dense layer to 1.

```
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='output_layer')(x_model)
```

Image generators (Only one folder with images)

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                    shear_range = 0.3,
                                    zoom_range = 0.3,
                                    rotation_range = 0.3,
                                    vertical_flip = True,
                                    horizontal_flip = True)

    validate_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                        target_size = (size, size),
                                        batch_size = batch_size,
                                        class_mode = 'binary')


validate_generator = validate_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                                    target_size = (size, size),
                                    batch_size = batch_size,
                                    class_mode = 'binary')
```

Then the trainings :

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                         epochs = epochs,
                         validation_data = validate_generator,
                         class_weight = class_weight, 
                         steps_per_epoch=int(train_generator.samples/batch_size),
                         callbacks=callbacks_list, 
                         validation_steps = int(validate_generator.samples/batch_size),
                           )
```

I am getting validation accuracy to be 100% as I don't have second folder. But testing accuracy is zero. (this is not the case when I did two class binary classification model).

With the single class, I thought neural network will get trained on single set of images and will give everything else as 0. Apparently its not working that way. Now I am running a another training session with the same good images and all other junk images.

Any recommendations how I could do it ? I would like to use Keras libraries as much as I could since I am learning Python as well with this.